# Why can't we recommend Biblical Hermeneutics when closing / flagging?

Tags: discussion, flagging, migration, off-topic

When flagging an answer with `needs improvement` we are taken to the same options for **closing** where we can select:

> **A community-specific reason**

and then:

> **This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network**

Here I expect to be able to choose **[Biblical Hermeneutics](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/)**. But the only option available here is

> **belongs on [meta.christianity.stackexchange.com](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/)**

Shouldn't we be able to recommend migration to Biblical Hermeneutics?

Sample questions in the past month that could benefit from having this option: [this](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/91106/10672) and [this](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/90761/10672).

Comment: [Duplicate question, but a great answer by SE staff](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/4638/3961)

Comment: @curiousdannii or other moderators Hasn't BH.SE graduated already?  Can this question be re-evaluated?  I don't think the accepted answer is valid anymore.  See [DKing's comment from 2017](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2147/why-cant-we-recommend-biblical-hermeneutics-when-flagging#comment15349_2148).  I was trying to suggest migration for [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/90761/10672).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Migration paths are set up only between graduated sites. We've completed our end of this bargain, but until Biblical Hermeneutics graduates we will not be able to have a migration path to or from them.

Comment: Thank you, that's answered my direct question. But this is a bit chicken and egg - by directing questions there we may help it graduate.

Comment: @Wikis Agree or not, graduation is a requirement for migration paths. Keep in mind that mods can migrate to any site so if you think something is a much better fit there, feel free to flag it as such.

Comment: What about Judaism? We've migrated there before.

Comment: @fredsbend we could request one, but the migrations to there are pretty rare, and I believe they have to be handled carefully as the tone of the two sites is pretty different

Comment: @waxeagle Yeah, I tried to use the site recently and was put off by the stringent on-topic rules. They have no "Brothers we are not Christians" post. In fact, they have quite a few posts saying the opposite. Though their about page says "answer everything about Judaism" that is actually not even close to the case.

Comment: @Wikis: For more information about migration paths, please see my [answer about a BH => C path](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/651/68).  It is a chicken-and-egg problem in more ways than one.  The truth is, default paths don't mean too much on smaller sites, like this one.  The moderators don't need an extra hint to know where the flagger intended a question to go.  ;-)

Comment: @fredsbend: FYI: I've had [good luck](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/971/jon-ericson) asking earnest questions and all my answers are accepted. YMMV.  I think the key is to show an interest in Judaism itself.

Comment: @fredsbend, if you wish to discuss in more detail the content of your comment of 2013-09-02 20:31:13Z, I invite you to raise your concerns in Judaism Stack Exchange's [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/468).

Comment: I know this is an old topic, but because the case still remains the same, perhaps, it's all the more relevant. Beta sites probably aren't allowed because they haven't been deemed a successful alternative yet. If that's the case, and if Hermaneutics is still in Beta, then perhaps it follows that there is not yet, by SE standards, a sufficiently distinct better option for the question. I just wanted to add that thought in there since it's been several years.

Comment: I agree with @DKing.  Haven't BH.SE graduated by now?  I think this answer is no longer correct.

Answer (score 1):

We (mods) can migrate to BH.se now, just close as

- Community Specific

  - Belongs on another site

    - Search for Biblical (no one knows how to spell Herman-new-ticks)

And close the question that way.

---

If a post is pointlessly accruing answers that don't belong on the site and nobody is voting to close, raising a mod flag is OK too. Its' better to have things migrated and moderated by the community, but migration is pretty cut 'n' dry.

However, we still only want to migrate questions that wouldn't be closed on BH.se.  So they should be about one verse, not doctrinaire and ideally have the verse in the post.

Comment: Only mods have that search box. Regular users currently can only migrate to this Meta site.

Comment: @curiousdannii Exactly.  Is it much trouble to add it for regular user?

Comment: @GratefulDisciple We'd have to ask staff. Question is if it's worth it. I'm not sure on the migration stats. Might look later.

Comment: @curiousdannii Sure, it may not worth the effort.  The question that we non-mods have for the mods: how would you like us to recommend migration to BH.SE?   Is posting a comment enough, or would you like us to flag it or close vote it too?

Comment: @GratefulDisciple Start with a comment, raise a flag later if it doesn't look like we noticed.