# Why is the only option for "off-topic because it should be migrated to another SE site" our meta site?

Tags: feature-request

From time to time I believe a question is better suited for another Stack Exchange site.  Most often, hermeneutics.SE.  However, when you try to flag a question as off-topic because it should be migrated to another SE site, the only option is our own Meta site.  Is there a reason why that's the only option, or can we at least add hermeneutics.SE to the list?

---

**EDIT**—The questioned referred to and its accepted answer state that back in 9/2013 hermeneutics.SE had not "graduated" and therefore we could not add such a link.  Have they still not graduated?  If no, then this question is certainly a duplicate.  If yes, this question is not a duplicate.

Comment: @bruisedreed, I believe this question is only a duplicate if, after 3 years, H.SE still hasn't graduated.

Comment: It hasn't, it's still exactly the same situation. Of graduated sites, the most relevant is still probably Judaism and [wax eagle's comment](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2147/why-cant-we-recommend-biblical-hermeneutics-when-flagging#comment4995_2148) still applies. After that it's probably  EL&U - even rarer. It's always an option to just flag for moderator attention instead which is required for non-graduated sites anyway.

Comment: Yeah. Exactly the same situation. But it will all be different in 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: @fredsbend, do they graduate in 6-8 weeks?

Comment: @jbh that's the hebrew equivalent of 40 years in  stackexchange speak https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/1765

Comment: @PeterTurner, after laughing for some time and enjoying the rich tradition that is Stack Exchange, I bow to the fact that this ain't never gonna happen in my reasonable lifetime and it's a better world to simply flag a moderator with, "this is a bit more complicated than the auto-flagging system wants to allow."  Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure the information on [Wax Eagle's answer](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2148/4) is complete or correct. You can flag for "other reasons" and recommend to the mods that the the question be migrated to BH.SE and we can do it.   He does mention this in a comment though.

I, personally, don't like migrating questions to their site unless it matches up with their [handy flowchart](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/867/a-helpful-flowchart-for-asking-questions-on-bh-se) I think I've migrated one question so far in almost a year of being a moderator. If a person asks a question here, we might want to give them the benefit of the doubt that they want a denominationally scoped answer and consider the question to be in the "needs improvement" camp rather then the "need migration" camp.

Futhermore, you'd probably have to impress @Caleb with a case for migrations since he's the Akela of the mods here and at BH.SE. I defer to his judgement in migration cases, but he's usually too quick on the ball to wait for my deferment anyway.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I didn't know @Caleb was so involved on both sites.  It'd be nice to hear his recommendation before we close off this question.

Comment: Peter, I removed my answer as I believe I misunderstood the question.  Glad you chimed in.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Oh, sorry I didn't mean your answer wasn't complete or correct,  I meant the answer that JBH was linking to.  You're right they do have the right of refusal (as in they'll get annoyed and tell us to stop)